# Find a cyclic sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Given that

$$ \frac{a}{bc-a^2}+\frac{b}{ca-b^2}+\frac{c}{ab-c^2}=0,\quad a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}, $$

find the value of

$$ \frac{a}{(bc-a^2)^2}+\frac{b}{(ca-b^2)^2}+\frac{c}{(ab-c^2)^2}. $$

I solved it via direct computation which is clearly not the best way to do. Is there any simple transformation I could perform or geometical meaning of this equation?

Comment: What value did you find?, it can help those who want to work on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From first equation (get rid of the denumerators) we get $$abc(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)= a^2b^2(a+b)+b^2c^2(b+c)+c^2a^2(c+a)$$ which can be easly transforemd to $$abc(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca)= (a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)(a+b+c)$$ so $$abc(a+b+c)^2= (a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)(a+b+c)$$

Now if $a+b+c\neq 0$ then we have $$\color{red}{abc(a+b+c)= a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}$$

But since \begin{align}a^2b^2 +b^2c^2&\geq 2b^2ac \\
b^2c^2 +c^2a^2&\geq 2c^2ab \\
c^2a^2 +a^2b^2&\geq 2a^2bc \\
\end{align}
we have always $$abc(a+b+c)\leq  a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2$$

with equality iff $a=b=c$. So, since we have equality sign in red equation, we deduce that $a=b=c$, but this can not hold since then fractions are not defined.

So $\boxed{a+b+c =0}$ and now I suppose it is not difficult to finish....

---

> Let $E$ be the expression. Then $$E = b\Big(\frac{1}{(ca-b^2)^2}-\frac{1}{(bc-a^2)^2}\Big)+      c\Big(\frac{1}{(ab-c^2)^2} -\frac{1}{(bc-a^2)^2}\Big) $$ Value in each big bracket is $0$ so $E=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\left(\dfrac a{bc-a^2}+\dfrac b{ca-b^2}+\dfrac c{ab-c^2}\right)\cdot{\underbrace{\left(\dfrac1{bc-a^2}+\dfrac1{ca-b^2}+\dfrac1{ab-c^2}\right)}_{\text{assuming this to be finite}}}$$

$$= \underbrace{\dfrac a{(bc-a^2)^2}+\dfrac b{(ca-b^2)^2}+\dfrac c{(ab-c^2)^2}}_{\text{this is to be calculated}}+\dfrac{(a+b)(ab-c^2)+(b+c)(bc-a^2)+(c+a)(ca-b^2)}{(bc-a^2)(ab-c^2)(ca-b^2)}$$

Now $(a+b)(ab-c^2)+(b+c)(bc-a^2)+(c+a)(ca-b^2)=\cdots=0$

We only need $(bc-a^2)(ab-c^2)(ca-b^2)\ne0$

${\quad a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}, {\text { is not actually required}}}$

Comment: I don't understand. What are you calculating?

Comment: @Aqua, Observe that   $$\dfrac a{bc-a^2}+\dfrac b{ca-b^2}+\dfrac c{ab-c^2}$$  $$\dfrac{\sum_{\text{ cyc}}(a+b)(ab-c^2)}{(bc-a^2)(ab-c^2)(ca-b^2)}$$ both are zero. Replace their values

Comment: Yes, and ..............???

Comment: And it is not clear at all that second expression is $0$.

Comment: I'm down voting, because your caculations are not correct and incomplete. How do you know that second big bracket is not $0$? If you multiply something with $0$ you will get $0$.

Comment: @Aqua, $$(a+b)(ab-c^2)+(b+c)(bc-a^2)+(c+a)(ca-b^2)$$  $$=a^2b+ab^2-c^2a-bc^2+(b^2c+bc^2-ca^2-c^2a)+(c^2a+ca^2-b^2c-bc^2)=0$$ right

Comment: That should be writen in an answer not in comment. Also my objection still holds. Your calculations are still wrong and misleading.

Comment: @Aqua, $$\sum{\text{cyc}}$$ means the expansion only! What's $$\dfrac{a^2}{bc-a^2}+\dfrac{b^2}{ca-b^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{ab-c^2}$$  from the first line of my post ? I consciously left the answer incomplete to be completed by the user who seems to be satisfied with the post.

Comment: Well I honesly don't know why is satisfied.

Comment: @Aqua, Do you see the solution, now?

Comment: You are quite arogant guy, I know what solution is, I don't need explanation. If you are writing an answer to someone than do it correctly. You are just fishing points. And your ''corrections'' are still insuficient.